# Am-Progressiv mit Kopulaverb?

Tags: grammar-identification

> ?Er ist am Lesersein / Leser-sein.
> ?Er ist Leser am Sein.

Im Sinne von:

> Er ist **dabei**, ein Leser zu sein.

Orientiert an:

> Er ist am Autofahren.
> Er ist den Staubsauger am Reparieren.

Um nicht einfach auszusagen, dass er ein Leser ist, sondern dass er *derzeit* ein Leser ist. Das kann ironisch gemeint sein, im Sinne dass die Person kein *richtiger* Leser ist, sondern nur einen *imitiert*.

Kennt ihr diese Verwendung? Ich habe sie schon mehrfach gehört. Ist es Umgangssprache?

Answer (score 1):

Dein Beispiel (die letzten beiden) ist auch (mit einem Augenzwinkern) als "Rheinische Verlaufsform" bekannt. Ähnliche Formen sind auch in anderen (aber bei weitem nicht allen) deutschen Dialekten gebräuchlich. Üblicherweise beschränkt sich die Verwendung auf die Umgangssprache, im Schriftdeutsch gibt es diese Formen nicht.

Man sollte dabei bedenken, dass Umgangssprache keinen besonderen Wert auf *absolute Exaktheit*, sondern eher auf *unangestrengte, Verständlichkeit* und *Kürze* legt. Bedeutet eine Konstruktion also einen höheren Aufwand, so wird sie sich in der Umgangssprache mit Sicherheit nicht durchsetzen.

Deine Konstruktionen mit "sein" hören sich sehr konstruiert an (ich kann mich auch nicht erinnern, sie jemals irgendwo gehört zu haben) - In der Umgangssprache würden sie sich deshalb wohl eher nicht durchsetzen. Anstatt "er ist am Leser sein" würde man wohl eher keinen verständlislosen Bllick riskieren und "Er liest gerade viel" sagen und in allen deutschsprachigen Regionen verstanden werden.

Answer (score 0):

Ich habe das noch nie gehört, es soll aber Dialekte geben, in denen diese Ausdrucksweise üblich ist.

Die Beispiele mit dem Lesen sind allerdings noch seltsamer, und die Erläuterung dazu ebenfalls. Was soll es bedeuten, dass jemand derzeit ein Leser ist? Jemand, der derzeit in der Lage ist zu lesen? Jemand, der derzeit liest? Für letzteres würde ich sagen "er liest", ggf. "er ist am Lesen".

Das Wort "Leser" verbinde ich zunächst mit dem Kunden einer Zeitung/Zeitschrift ("unsere Leser"), unabhängig davon, ob sie gerade in diesem Moment etwas lesen oder nicht.

Comment: Ich habe bei "Leser" an "Jemand, der viel liest" gedacht.